# nested vs object in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

Can someone explain what is a difference between "object" and "nested" fields in documents in Elasticsearch?

I know by default field is defined as object. I also know that I can access object field with a dot like this: my_field.name, my_field.title etc.

Documentation for object: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html
Documentation for nestes:http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html

but I still cant understand a difference...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What your are calling "object" is probably "inner object" in elasticsearch.

Check this link to see the differences

https://web.archive.org/web/20140810095505/http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 1):

The question is asked long ago. Just to refresh the answer, [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) is the link to the latest documentation. It describes pretty well the difference how internally Elastic stores documents and find matches for queries