# How does "must" clause with an array of "match" clauses really mean?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, booleanquery

I have an elasticsearch `query` which looks like this...

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "match": {"attrs.name": "username"}
      }, {
        "match": {"attrs.value": "johndoe"}
      }]
    }
  }
```

... and documents in the index that look like this:

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "attrs": [{
    "name": "username",
    "value": "jimihendrix"
  }, {
    "name": "age",
    "value": 23
  }, {
    "name": "alias",
    "value": "johndoe"
  }]
}
```

Which of the following does this query *really* mean?

1. Document should contain either `attrs.name = username` OR `attrs.value = johndoe`
2. Or, document should contain, both, `attrs.name = username` AND `attrs.value = johndoe`, even if they may match **different elements** in the `attrs` array (this would mean that the document given above would **match** the query)
3. Or, document should contain, both, `attrs.name = username` AND `attrs.value = johndoe`, but they must match the **same element** in the `attrs` array (which would mean that the document given above would **not match** the query)

**Further,** how do I write a query to express #3 from the list above, i.e. the document should match only if a **single element** inside the `attrs` array matches **both** the following conditions:

- attrs.name = username
- attrs.value = johndoe

Comment: can you share your mapping?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I'm new to ES, so I may not get some basic terminology. What is "mapping"?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda, I tried it on you sample data and using `nested` data type got the expected output, please refer to my answer . Mapping means how you model you data in Elasticsearch ie what type of fields to use, what analyzer to use, you can think of it as table definition of SQL, please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html for more details.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda did you get a chance to go through my answer, let me know if you need more infomation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Must** stands for **"And"** so a document satisfying all the clauses in match query is returned.

Must will not satisfy point 1. Document should contain either attrs.name = username OR attrs.value = johndoe- you need a should clause which works like "OR"

Whether Must will satisfy Point 2 or point 3 depends on the type of "attrs" field.

If "attr" field type is [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) then fields are flattened that is no relationship maintained between different fields for array. So must query will return a document if any attrs.name="username" and attrs.value="John doe", even if they are not part of same object in that array.

If you want an object in an array to act like a separate document, you need to use [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) field and use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to match documents

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "attrs",
      "inner_hits": {}, --> returns matched nested documents
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "attrs.name": "username"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "attrs.value": "johndoe"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

hits in the response will contain all nested documents , to get all matched nested documents , inner_hits has to be specified

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements you need to define your `attrs` field as nested, please refer [nested type in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for more information. **Disclaimer : it maintains the relationship but costly to query.**

Answer to your other two questions also depends on what data type you are using please refer [nested vs object data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321366/nested-vs-object-in-elasticsearch) for more details

**Edit: solution using sample mapping, example docs and expected result**

### Index mapping using nested type

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "attrs": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index 2 sample doc one which severs the criteria and other which doesn't

```
{
    "attrs": [
        {
            "name": "username",
            "value": "johndoe"
        },
        {
            "name": "alias",
            "value": "myname"
        }
    ]
}
```

Another which serves criteria

```
{
    "attrs": [
        {
            "name": "username",
            "value": "jimihendrix"
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "value": 23
        },
        {
            "name": "alias",
            "value": "johndoe"
        }
    ]
}
```

### And search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "attrs",
      "inner_hits": {}, 
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "attrs.name": "username"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "attrs.value": "johndoe"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### And Search result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "nested",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.7509375,
                "_source": {
                    "attrs": [
                        {
                            "name": "username",
                            "value": "johndoe"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "alias",
                            "value": "myname"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "attrs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.7509375,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "nested",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "2",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "attrs",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 1.7509375,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "name": "username",
                                        "value": "johndoe"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```